# python can't load on VS Code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I develop in Djangon / Python recently and use until now Sublime Text.
I would like to go to a more complete idea (console, debug, etc ...)
so I installed VS Code but when I open a project Django / Python I have the error below when I wanted to install the python extension but I had the error below:

> The environment variable 'Path' seems to have some paths containing the '"' character. The existence of such a character is known to have caused the Python extension to not load. If the extension fails to load please modify your paths to remove this '"' character.

when I look at the PATH environment variable I do not see quotes but 2 lines:

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\lib;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3;C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts;
>
> C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

I decided to followed the tutorial VS Code Python and actually when I run the program "Hello world!" I have the error message below:

> [Running] python -u "c:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\hello\hello.py"
> 'python' Is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file in Python?

When I run my django project with windows console, I use py instead of python... I don't know why and if it is me that set this VS Code use python...
maybe it is the origin of the problem

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you translate error message in English?

Comment: I have edited the error message (see above) and infact I have tested directly in VS code console to enter py -u "c:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\hello\hello.py" and it is effectivelly running ; can I change py with python?

Comment: Yes. you can.
It seems you are using python 3.7.4
To use python command, just downgrade the version of python to v3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You are actually executing code using Code Runner, not the Python extension (you can tell by the `[Running]` bit). If you would like the Python extension to do the execution then either disable Code Runner for your Python workspace or uninstall it.

Comment: thanks for replying ; I have desintall Code Runner and effectively it works ! but dealing with the first problem? is-it a problem or not?

Comment: @SLATER you will need to backslash escape quotes in your path; it's a JSON thing.

Comment: could tell me how precisely? I read I do not have to escpae space in JSON

Comment: If you have a quote in your path, write it as `\"`.

Comment: But i do non have any: C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

Comment: @SLATER sorry, misread that issue; didn't pick up on the fact it's about your `PATH` environment variable. If the extension is installing and working then don't worry about it.